# Advice on how to create a leaderboard in flutter

Tags: android, arrays, flutter

I am creating a leaderboard in flutter and i want the data for my leaderboard to use a dynamic array but i do not have any idea on how to do this can someone suggest a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is not a flutter specific solution.

let's say you have a list called leaderboard list.

Every time the list is updated(after fetching the data) run a sort function and assign the sorted list.